# How to refactor coloring of certain td elements?

Tags: html, css, firefox-addon

I'm coloring specific td elements by declaring:

```
td[style*="background-color: #ffc"], td[style*="background-color: #fb9"], 
td[style*="background-color: #bfc"], td[style*="background-color: #fcc"] {
background-color: #0d1117 !important;
}
```

How can I refactor this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a pseudo-class in CSS called `:is` that makes you delete the code repetition

```css
td:is([style*="background-color: #ffc"], [style*="background-color: #fb9"], [style*="background-color: #bfc"], [style*="background-color: #fcc"]) {
    background-color: #0d1117 !important;
}
```

> documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is

---

or you can use `javascript` by using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)!

**how it works:**
you have two variables, 
 the first needs an array of hex color codes. 
 the second variable needs the final color you want the element to be colored.

**how to make it work on my project:**

1. create a `<script>` tag or a javascript file.
2. insert this code inside it:

```js
let colorsArray = ["ffc", "fb9", "bfc", "fcc"]; // change this line
let finalColor = "0d1117";

colorsArray.forEach((color) => {
    let tdWithColor = document.querySelectorAll(`td[style*="background-color: #${color}"]`);

    tdWithColor.forEach((element) => {
        element.style = `background-color: #${finalColor}`;
    })
});

// watch the code snippet below if you want comments
```

3. change the variables to what you need.

---

**code snippet with demo example:**

```js
let colorsArray = ["ffc", "fb9", "bfc", "fcc"]; // change this line... don't put "#" in the beginning (js automatically adding it)
let finalColor = "0d1117"; // your final color, don't put "#" in the beginning (js automatically adding it)

/* Don't change the lines below */

/* for every color we are adding this logic below */
colorsArray.forEach((color) => {
  /* getting all the html elements with the same color */
  let tdWithColor = document.querySelectorAll(`td[style*="background-color: #${color}"]`);

  /* if there is more than one td of the same color we are coloring it too */
  tdWithColor.forEach((element) => {
    element.style = `background-color: #${finalColor}`;
  })
});
```

```html
    <!-- this is only a example -->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <!-- I am creating multiple elements with the same bg color to test javascript  -->
            <td style="background-color: #ffc">FFC</td>
            <td style="background-color: #ffc">FFC</td>
            <td style="background-color: #ffc">FFC</td>

            <td style="background-color: #fb9">FB9</td>
            <td style="background-color: #fb9">FB9</td>
            <td style="background-color: #fb9">FB9</td>

            <td style="background-color: #bfc">BFC</td>
            <td style="background-color: #bfc">BFC</td>
            <td style="background-color: #bfc">BFC</td>

            <td style="background-color: #fcc">FCC</td>
            <td style="background-color: #fcc">FCC</td>
            <td style="background-color: #fcc">FCC</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: if you want simpler solution, can I use javascript? so I change the answer.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Yeah sure if you know even a better way with javascript you can post it as well :)

Comment: added javascript example, just change the array with the colors, the other things automatically javascript do it for you. basically I used 2 `forEach` loops and that's it (problem solved).